# Delete uploaded file with a wrong name as the defined

Tags: php, codeigniter

Below is my upload function in codeigniter. I can upload a file. I also check if the file name matches the url parameter. How do i delete the file if the name does not match the url. I have tried unlink function but it does not work

```
function do_upload() {

    $this->makeDir();

    $labref = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $filename = 'xyz/'. date('Y').'/'.date('M').'/'. $labref .'/' . $labref . '.xlsx';
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $data['labref'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['settings_view'] = 'analyst_file_present_v';
        $this->base_params($data);
    } else {

        $config['upload_path'] = 'xyz/'. date('Y').'/'.date('M').'/'. $labref  ;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $data=  $this->upload->data();
        if ($data['file_name']=="$labref.'.xlsx'") {                
          $this->SaveFileDetails();
        $this->success();
        }else{            
         $filename = 'xyz/'.date('Y').'/'.date('M').'/'. $labref.'/'.$labref.'xlsx'  ;
           unlink($filename);
           echo 'You have uploaded a wrong file';
        }

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('worksheet')) {
            $data['labref'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

            $data['settings_view'] = 'upload_analyst_v';
            $this->base_params($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `unlink`.  Check your file permissions.  And, what type of error messsage are you getting?

Comment: are you sure about path in `$filename`?

Comment: I have used unlink in the posted code. There is no error at all, it uploads the file and echoes 'You have uploaded a wrong file' as is in the code segment above

Comment: I have echoed the path name and it has returned the correct path

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are trying to delete the wrong file.

You should replace:

```
$filename = 'xyz/'.date('Y').'/'.date('M').'/'. $labref.'/'.$labref.'xlsx'  ;
```

with:

```
$filename = 'xyz/'.date('Y').'/'.date('M').'/'. $labref.'/' . $data['file_name'];
```

To delete the uploaded file.

**Edit:** You have to actually do the upload before you can access the errors and data so you should move your `$this->upload->do_upload()` block to before the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest jeroen, i tried it and it did not go through

Comment: echo $data['file_name'] returns blank

Answer (score 0):

You've got some pretty nasty quote mismatches:

```
    if ($data['file_name']=="$labref.'.xlsx'") {                
                                     ^-----^---
```

Since you're in a double-quoted string, those `'`  are going to become part of the filename. Perhaps you meant:

```
   if ($data['file_name']== $labref .'.xlsx') {
```

instead? (note lack of `"`.

Comment: I have done just that, still no success, i have tried to echo $data['file_name]; and it echoes blank